# restTemplate.getForEntity() maps with status code 200 but fails to set values

Tags: spring, mapping, resttemplate

Making a Get call to a Sports Api provider and I call the method, getForEntity with a `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`

After the exchange, I get a 200 status code and a response with 666 items.

Problem is, they are all set to null or 0.

The Json they send has fields capital to begin with. example: `"TeamID": 1`,

I've tried to set my class fields as `teamID` and `TeamID`. No luck
I've also tried to make a wrapper response class with a list of the mapped object.

```java
public class SportsDataTeam {

    private Integer teamID; // changed from float to Integer
    private String school;
    private String name;
    private String teamLogoUrl;
    private String shortDisplayName;

   //with standard generated getters and setters below example 

}



//Then in my service class, I call:

 ResponseEntity<SportsDataTeam[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
"https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/cbb/scores/json/teams?key=df57fbe761424db78e5c16a103ceb0d0",
                SportsDataTeam[].class);
```

Here are the first two items in the request: 
Its a length of 666 -- but to save space, only the first two of the array

```
[
{
"TeamID": 1,
"Key": "SMU",
"Active": true,
"School": "SMU",
"Name": "Mustangs",
"ApRank": null,
"Wins": 15,
"Losses": 17,
"ConferenceWins": 6,
"ConferenceLosses": 12,
"GlobalTeamID": 60000001,
"ConferenceID": 1,
"Conference": "American Athletic",
"TeamLogoUrl": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/1.png",
"ShortDisplayName": "SMU",
"Stadium": {
"StadiumID": 101,
"Active": true,
"Name": "Moody Coliseum",
"Address": null,
"City": "Dallas",
"State": "TX",
"Zip": null,
"Country": null,
"Capacity": 7000
}
},
{
"TeamID": 2,
"Key": "TEMPL",
"Active": true,
"School": "Temple",
"Name": "Owls",
"ApRank": null,
"Wins": 23,
"Losses": 10,
"ConferenceWins": 13,
"ConferenceLosses": 5,
"GlobalTeamID": 60000002,
"ConferenceID": 1,
"Conference": "American Athletic",
"TeamLogoUrl": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static.fantasydata.com/logos/ncaa/2.png",
"ShortDisplayName": "TEMPLE",
"Stadium": {
"StadiumID": 45,
"Active": true,
"Name": "Liacouras Center",
"Address": null,
"City": "Philadelphia",
"State": "PA",
"Zip": null,
"Country": null,
"Capacity": 10200
}
}
]
```

Comment: Also, I removed the comma after the last "}" just so this example would be valid JSON still

Comment: You can actually copy that URL and see the response if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello [Braden Borman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8934374/braden-borman)

If your JSON has keys are in CAPS like `TeamID` instead of `teamId`, then you need to add `@JsonProperty` annotation to your attributes.

Update of `SportsDataTeam.java`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SportsDataTeam {

    @JsonProperty("TeamID")
    private Integer teamId;
    @JsonProperty("Key")
    private String key;
    @JsonProperty("Active")
    private Boolean active;
    @JsonProperty("School")
    private String school;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("ApRank")
    private String apRank;
    @JsonProperty("Wins")
    private Integer wins;
    @JsonProperty("Losses")
    private Integer losses;
    @JsonProperty("ConferenceWins")
    private Integer conferenceWins;
    @JsonProperty("ConferenceLosses")
    private Integer conferenceLosses;
    @JsonProperty("GlobalTeamID")
    private Long globalTeamId;
    @JsonProperty("ConferenceID")
    private Integer conferenceId;
    @JsonProperty("Conference")
    private String conference;
    @JsonProperty("TeamLogoUrl")
    private String teamLogoUrl;
    @JsonProperty("ShortDisplayName")
    private String shortDisplayName;
    @JsonProperty("Stadium")
    private Stadium stadium;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Update of `Stadium.java`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Stadium {

    @JsonProperty("StadiumID")
    private Integer stadiumId;
    @JsonProperty("Active")
    private Boolean active;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private String address;
    @JsonProperty("City")
    private String city;
    @JsonProperty("State")
    private String state;
    @JsonProperty("Zip")
    private Integer zip;
    @JsonProperty("Country")
    private String country;
    @JsonProperty("Capacity")
    private Integer capacity;

    // getters & setters

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you kindly for taking time and for the input! 

Ill try it out soon! :)